# Is there any concept in physics, that could potentially in the future get rid of "randomness"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, determinism, randomness

This question was very interesting to a non physicists like me [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/153893/)  (I am computer scientist and I work with "pure random" crypto hardware that uses quantum phenomena) Obviously string theory was not the answer. But is there any hope of explaining why phenomena that we see today es purely random, is explained in a deterministic manner if other dimensions or unknown variables so far come into play? or it is known that this will never happen and the randomness is random not because we ignore some other variables?

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden-variable_theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden-variable_theory)

Comment: Are you asking about randomness in general or in quantum mechanics?

Comment: I guess in quantum mechanics, ( of course it would be also interesting to know if the cosmos could be deterministic and it just has a a very big amount of variables). Acoording to the link of hidden variables " Bell's theorem would later suggest that local hidden variables (a way for finding a complete description of reality) of certain types are impossible" So, it is proven that the cosmos can't be deterministic? Or is it an open question?

Comment: The universe isnt deterministic.

Comment: @JunSeo-He is this proven, or is it just the way we can understand it now?

Comment: According to the Standard Model of elementary particles which describes all fundamental particles and interactions except gravity the universe seems not to be deterministic.

Comment: " randomness is random not because we ignore some other variables" -> in classical mechanics (i.e. "throw a dice"), it is like that because we ignore the exact initial state of the "system" (i.e. the "dice"). Classical chaos theory is deterministic but "practically random" (the famous butterfly effect story). On the other hand, QM is "ontologically random", unless one believes in the "hidden variables" (see @J.Delaney comment).

Comment: @JunSeo-He We believe the standard model (in it's current form at least) does not explain everything so the question of determinism (and all variations on that) is still open.  Certainly there are many very clever people working on developing theories with refinements to e.g. hidden variables.